# Creating nested collection of objects with parent-child structure using Java Streams API?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two simple classes Order and Item. Each Order contains list of Items. How to create a list of Orders using Java Streams?

Order:

```
public Order(String name, int id, ArrayList<Item> items) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.items = items;
}
```

Item

```
public Item(String name, int id, double price, boolean active) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.price = price;
    this.active = active;
}
```

Format for the `name` field should go something like this: `Order 3`.
Format for the `name` field should go something like this: `Item 4 of Order 3`

Here is my lame attempt:

```
 ArrayList<Order> or = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,NUMBER_OF_ORDERS).boxed()
                .map(idOrder -> 
                        new Order("Orderd " + idOrder.toString(), idOrder,      
                    IntStream.rangeClosed(1,NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_ORDER).boxed()
                        .map(idItem -> new Item("Item " + idItem, idItem, 100, 
                            true))
                          .collect(Collectors .toCollection(ArrayList::new)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))));
```

I'm getting an error. My ideas was to call a Stream in place of 3rd parameter in Order constructor to return a ArrayList of Items and then again to wrap all Order objects in a list, but it is not going well...

Comment: Please the constructor of both classes. And explain how your attempt is not ok

Comment: I added const, but SO informed me that there is too much code, I'll update question in a bit.

Comment: Just the constructor, not all the class

Comment: Don’t insist on the result to be an `ArrayList`. Then, you can use `Collectors.toList()`, to get a `List`. Instead of `.boxed().map(…)`, you can use `.mapToObj(…)` (you’ve shown to already know this). Further, instead of `IntStream.rangeClosed(1,NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_ORDER)`, you can use `IntStream.range(0,NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_ORDER)`. But I don’t see anything “lame” in this attempt. When you are “getting an error”, you should post that error.

Comment: Why not just use loops?

Comment: @NomadMaker I'm practicing Streams...

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. I've just set `collect` in appropriate places. But if someone has better idea, it would be great to post it here. Cheers!

```
List<Order> or = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, NUMBER_OF_ORDERS).boxed()
            .map(idOrder -> 
                    new Order("Orderd " + idOrder, idOrder,         
                    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_ORDER)
                    .mapToObj(idItem -> new Item("Item " + idItem + " of Order " + idOrder, 100, true))
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)))
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```